# Angle Chasing in a convex quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, angle, quadrilateral

Find the measures of the angles of the convex quadrilateral ABCD, if $\angle ACD = 78°$ , $\angle BDC = 22°$, $\angle CBD = 12°$ and $\angle CAD = 24°$.

Source: Romanian Mathematical Gazette

Comment: Consider the intersection of $\overline{BD}$ and $\overline{AC}$, recalling that triangles have $180^\circ$ and that vertically opposite angles are equal you should have a number of ways to find the angles of your quadrilateral.

Comment: @AlejandroJimenezTellado I did that but I’m stuck at finding the measures of CAB and DBA. I found that their sum is 100 degrees

Comment: HINT. $\angle CAD=2\angle CBD$. Hence...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Let P be the intersection of the bisector of angle A with diagonal BD. From here it follows that PAC=PBC= 12 degrees. From here it follows that the quadrilateral ABCP is cyclic and from here the problem can be easily completed. Thank you for the hint

Comment: It's not very nice to invite someone to chat, and then to delete the question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734899/symmetrical-parabolas-about-a-point

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did it by accident  since it was late at night and I’m new to this site. I’m very sorry for the inconvenience that I had caused. I reopened the question.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in the quadrilateral $AB=AC=AD$.[image: angles in quadrilateral]

Thus $\triangle ACD$ is isosceles and$$\angle ADC=78^o$$Next, since $\triangle ABD$ is isosceles, then$$\angle ABD=\angle ADB=78-22=56^o$$so that $$\angle ABC=56+12=68^o$$Again, since $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles, then $\angle ACB=\angle ABC=68^o$, and$$\angle BCD=68+78=146^o$$Lastly, since $\angle CAB=180-2\cdot 68=44^o$, then$$\angle DAB=44+24=68^o$$

Comment: Since $\angle DAC=2\angle DBC$, you know that $B$ lies on the circumference of the circle whose center is $A$ and whose circumference passes through $C$ and $D$.  Thus $AB=AC=AD$.

Answer (score 0):

After calculating some angles with the given information we find that $\angle ADC = \angle ACD = 78^\circ$. Therefore $\triangle ACD$ is isosceles. Let $P$ and $P'$ be the intersection of the bisector of angle $A$ with diagonal $BD$ and $CD$. Since $\triangle ACD$  is isosceles and $AP'$ is the angle bisector of $A$ it results that $AP'$ is also perpendicular on $CD$ and $P'$ is the midpoint of $CD$. Thus $PP'$ is the median and height in the $\triangle DPC$.

Hence it follows that $\triangle DPC$  is isosceles. Then $\angle PDC = \angle PCD = 22^\circ$. Thus $\angle ACP =56^\circ$. Since $ABCP$ is cyclic $\angle ABP = \angle ACP = 56^\circ$. Hence $\angle BAC = 100^\circ-56^\circ = 44^\circ$.