# Symmetrical parabolas about a point

Tags: functions, quadratics, graphing-functions

Let the functions $f_1, f_2: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $f_1(x) = x^2 - 2x + 4$ and $f_2(x) = -x^2 + 6x - 10$. We denote $P_1$ and $P_2$ the graphs of the two functions in the same $XY$ plane, and $V_1$ and $V_2$ the vertices of the parabolas $P_1$ and $P_2$, respectively. Prove that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are symmetrical about the midpoint of $V_1V_2$.

Comment: I think we need to show that the distance from any point on one parabola to the midpoint is equal to the distance from the corresponding point on the other parabola to the same midpoint but I keep getting stuck.

Comment: Can you start by finding that midpoint?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Lets denote M the midpoint. After some calculations M has the coordinates (2;1)

Comment: OK, now, consider the line through $(2,1)$ with slope $t$; it has the equation $y-1=t(x-2)$. Can you find the intersection of that line with each of the parabolas, and then show that those two intersection points are symmetrical with respect to $(2,1)$?

Comment: Can you find the intersection of $y-1=t(x-2)$ with $y=x^2-2x+4$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147182/discussion-between-math-enthusiast9-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat – let's continue the discussion here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If the midpoint has the coordinates $(x_0,y_0)$, is it correct to prove that $f_1(x_0-x)+f_2(x_0+x)=2y_0$?

Answer (score 1):

The midpoint, as you have found, is at $M=(2,1)$.

Now we need to show that given any point $P=(a,b)$ on the first parabola there's a point $Q=(c,d)$ on the second parabola that is symmetrical to $P$ with respect to $M$. That is to say, $P+Q=2M$ (so $M$ is the midpoint of the line segment joining $P$ and $Q$), which we can rewrite as $Q=2M-P$, which is $(c,d)=2(2,1)-(a,b)=(4-a,2-b)$.

So, we are assuming $b=a^2-2a+4$ (that just says $P$ is on the first parabola), and we want to show that $d=-c^2+6c-10$ (which just says $Q$ is on the second parabola). We have already seen that $c=4-a$ and $d=2-b$, so we want to show
$$
2-b=-(4-a)^2+6(4-a)-10. 
$$
Now if you multiply everything out in that equation, and combine like terms, you get exactly $b=a^2-2a+4$, and we're done.